# Is it possible Authorize.Net or any other payment gateway implement in Roku or SceneGraph?

Tags: scene, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on Roku TV application and our client want to build a "shopping" app using SceneGraph component. Also, client want to implement payment gateway Authorize.Net. Is it possible in Roku, if not then what is the alternate solution. Please provide suggestions to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to focus on the second part of the question - alternative solution. Why? Because You can probably implement Authorize.net somehowe but ROKU will not approve this kind of application and will not alow it to be on the official ROKU store.
Here is ROKU certification criteria, please notice chapter 2.1:
https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/certification/certification.md

So in order to go LIVE with application you need to implement ROKU PAY but also good tip is to contact ROKU directly and ask them if in your case, they would allow Authorize.Net since from my understanding Your client does not sell/have SVOD services.
Try to contact them using this: https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/contact

Comment: Yes, I think ROKU PAY would be that option for this kind of applications, but as U.Mitic suggest you should ask.